# Covering distance for a linear code

Tags: coding-theory

I'm currently working my way through "Fundemental of Error Correcting Codes" by Huffman and Pless. However I'm stuck on exercise 95 which states:

Suppose we have a linear code $\mathcal{C}$ with $B_q(n, d)$ codewords ($B_q(n, d)$ being the maximum number of codewords of a linear code with length $n$ and minimum distance at least $d$), then the exercise is to show that $\mathcal{C}$, has covering radius $d-1$ or less, meaning: $$ \mathbb{F}_q^n = \bigcup_{c \in \mathcal{C}} B_{d - 1}(c) $$ where $B_{r}(y) = \{x \in \mathbb{F}_q^n | d(x, y) \leq r\}$.

I have included their trick for when $\mathcal{C}$ is non-linear below:

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{F}_q^n \setminus \bigcup_{c \in \mathcal{C}} B_{d-1}(c)$, where $B_{d-1}$ are hamming balls of radius $d-1$. Then one can add $x$ to $\mathcal{C}$, (which contradicts the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ had the maximum number of codewords) but this doesn't exactly work in the linear case, since $\mathcal{C}' = \mathcal{C} \cup \{x\}$ is not necessarily a linear code. My next idea is to let $\mathcal{C}' = \mathcal{C} + span\{x\}$, but then i can't figure out the minimum distance of $\mathcal{C}'$. Any help would be much appricated.

Edit:

Sorry for the inconvenience, I have updatede the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: ill make sure to remember that :)

Comment: @MartinSigNørbjerg: It's not a question of remembering it for the future. There's an edit button under the question; you can add the parts of the image that are essential to your question.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question a little bit more to add what the exercise is asking for? Also, you are asking about minimum distance in the question but about covering distance in the title.  Which is it?

Comment: Hope the edit helps clear up any confusion. BR Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less the same argument still works. This is a typical use of linearity in coding theory.

---

Assume, as in your summary of the non-linear argument, that there exists a vector $x\in\Bbb{F}_q^n$ that does not belong to any ball of radius $d-1$ centered at a codeword. As you guessed, it follows that the linear code
$$
\mathcal{C}^+=\{y+ax\mid y\in\mathcal{C}, a\in\Bbb{F}_q\}
$$
will still have minimum Hamming distance $\ge d$, in violation of maximality of $\mathcal{C}$.

We see this as follows. Recall that for linear codes the minimum distance is equal to the minimum (non-zero) weight. So a contrapositive assumption is that there exists a word of the prescribed form
$$
z=y+ax\in\mathcal{C}^+
$$
of Hamming weight at most $d-1$. As the minimum weight of vectors of $\mathcal{C}$ is $d$, it follows that $z\notin\mathcal{C}$. In other words, $a\neq0$. But the Hamming weight does not change, when a codeword is multiplied by a non-zero scalar. It follows that the weight of the word
$$
-a^{-1}z=(-a^{-1}y)-x\in\mathcal{C}^+
$$
is also $\le d-1$. But then
$$
d_H(-a^{-1}y,x)=w(-a^{-1}y-x)\le d-1.
$$
This is a contradiction because it implies that the vector $x$ is in the ball $B_{d-1}(-a^{-1}y)$ of radius $d-1$ centered at the codeword $-a^{-1}y\in\mathcal{C}$.

Hence we can conclude that the covering radius of a maximal linear code of minimum distance $d$ is strictly less than $d$.

---

I was a bit disappointed that I could not find it here already, as the technique is pretty standard. I do recall having to think it through as a student of coding theory, but this becomes second nature quickly enough! [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4193882/11619) Kodlu is using this result in a different context (+1).